# Is there any FREE custom search api like google custom search?

Tags: api, search, rest, csc

I'm using google JSON/Atom Custom Search API now. The problem is the total queries are only 100 per day. Need to pay for extra queries.

Is there any **FREE**  Custom Search API? Maybe from Bing or Yahoo?

Thanks!

Comment: Cheapest that I found is yahoo 0.80$ per 1000 requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatives to Google Search are mainly developed for specific programming language as the following:

- **Searcharoo**, its open source and
  customisable. 
  http://searcharoo.codeplex.com/
- **lucene**, from apache open source and
  customisable.
  http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html

Answer (score 5):

Bing.com has a free search API: http://www.bing.com/developers/s/APIBasics.html
The free search is limited to 7 requests per second per IP

Comment: No, it is not. I up voted you and this is what I find ccc. https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/5BA839F1-12CE-4CCE-BF57-A49D98D29A44

Answer (score 2):

Bing.com has a free search *API: http://www.bing.com/developers/s/APIBasics.html* The free search is limited to 5000 requests.

Click [here](https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/explore/bing/search) after subscribing the BING search API for test the API for developer perspective,

Answer (score 1):

There is not available any api in java for search the google results. so you have only do for paid for this api and get the 1000 query for per day. and you can also visit this site for pricing policy https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview#Pricing

Comment: Dead link, please fix it or delete the answer.